# You fought so bravely for it. [adjunct vs. complement]

Tags: word-order, adjuncts

> *You fought so bravely for it.*

In this sentence, the verb 'fought' is followed by two dependents: *so bravely* and *for it*.

I thought that *for it* was a complement whereas *so bravely* was an adjunct. But then, I remember hearing that an adjunct cannot come between a verb and its complement.

Does this mean that *so bravely* here is a complement as well?
Or that an adjunct can come between a verb and a complement?
Or that actually both these dependents are adjuncts?

Comment: This question suits more at the English language stack exchange, Linguistics SE isn't meant for specific language's grammar.

Comment: @WiccanKarnak The question is OK. The rules say "ask about any natural language from a linguistics point of view, though I accept that this question, which is fairly basic, would be better suited to ELU.

Comment: "But then, I remember hearing that an adjunct cannot come between a verb and its complement." I think you've just found a good counterargument against that. See how many others you can find.

Comment: I'd say that "so bravely" is a manner adjunct, and "for it" is a complement licensed by "fought". In my experience the 'rule' is that an adjunct cannot come between a verb and its direct object. Consider these examples: "The suitcase is most definitely under the bed", where "most definitely" is an adjunct occurring between the verb and its complement "under the bed" / "We drove directly from Boston to New York", where the adjunct "directly" is located between the verb and its complement.

Comment: @BillJ Maybe the supposed "rule" that says 'an adjunct cannot come between a head and its complement' _is_ applicable to NP, but is not to VP. Am I right about this?

Comment: In my grammar, adjuncts are modifiers in clause structure (modifying verbs and verb phrases), not NP structure. But even if you do take them as modifiers generally, then the 'rule' fails, e.g. in _The withdrawal **indefinitely** of the ferry service_, the adverb/adjunct "indefinitely" is intervening between the noun head "withdrawal" and its complement "of the ferry service". I'm sure there are plenty of other similar examples.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for the counter-example. Then, there's no need to differentiate between complements and adjuncts at least when it comes to the word order. Or is there?

Comment: I agree with that (though some adjuncts are fussier about their position than others). Compare (1) "Ed drove directly from Boston to New York" and (2) "Ed drove from Boston to New York in a real hurry". "Directly" and "in a real hurry" are both adjuncts, though in (1) its linear position is between the verb and its complement, and in (2) it's after the complement.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the original unaccented phrase is

```
You fought for it so bravely
```

But since you give sentence stress to "so bravely" (raising it syntactically and thus privilege it semantically) it renders

```
You fought so bravely for it t_[so bravely]
```

This suggestion requires a theory that has some Focus or Accent etc. Phrase there above the lexical complement but below the verb. t means trace

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your point. Anyhow, you can put the adjunct virtually anywhere: _So bravely, you fought for it_ _You so bravely fought for it_ _You fought for it so bravely_

Comment: You say  you "remember hearing that an adjunct cannot come between a verb and its complement.", your comment here and my answer provide Focused examples (you focus on that they did it SO BRAVELY) thus with deviating word order.

Comment: @JK2 - I think this is a decisive argument for "so bravely" being an adjunct. There is much more freedom to place adjuncts than complements.